# Is this a mistake in this math book or am I misunderstanding something?

Tags: probability

I'm reading a book about the mathematics of poker, and towards the beginning they define how you determine what likelihood you need of winning in order to justify calling a certain bet in relation to the size of the pot. The equation is below, as well as an example of a bet of 60 into a pot of 400.

[Equation & Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWnrb.png)

Then, in the very next paragraph, an example is given where the authors seem to not include both their bet AND your bet in the "new pot size", but rather only include one bet. By my calculations, it should be 30/135, or 22%, and not 30/105, or 28%. Am I misunderstanding this?

[Contradictory Example?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iKYV.png)

Comment: Out of curiosity, which book is it?

Comment: @littleO The Mathematics of Poker by Bill Chen, widely considered the bible of poker math in the community.

Comment: By the way, ignore the typos in the transcription. Those happened when converting the written text to PDF form, but the numbers and situation are all the same as the written book. They propose in the second paragraph that a 30 bet into a 75 pot requires odds of 30/105 to call, when it appears that their introduction would claim that it requires odds of 30/135.